# Performing a Principal Component Analysis to reconstruct time series creates more values than expected

Tags: python-3.x, pca, finance, alpha-vantage

I want to do a Principal Component Analysis following [this notebook](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Python-for-Finance-Second-Edition/blob/master/Chapter06/Chapter%2006%20-%20Statistical%20Analysis%20of%20Time%20Series%20Data.ipynb) to reconstruct the DJIA (I'm using alpha_ventage) from its components (found with Quandl). Yet, it seems that I create more values than expected, than the original dataframe, when reconstructing the values multiplying the principal components by their weights

```
kernel_pca = KernelPCA(n_components=5).fit(df_z_components)
pca_5 = kernel_pca.transform(-daily_df_components)

weights = fn_weighted_average(kernel_pca.lambdas_)
reconstructed_values = np.dot(pca_5, weights)
```

Indeed, daily_df_components is created from the components of the DJIA by the quandl API which seem to have more data than the library I use to get the DJIA Index, alpha_ventage.

Here is the full code

```
"""
Obtaining the components data from quandl
"""
import quandl

QUANDL_API_KEY = 'MYKEY'
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = QUANDL_API_KEY

SYMBOLS = [
        'AAPL', 'MMM', 'BA', 'AXP', 'CAT',
        'CVX', 'CSCO', 'KO', 'DD', 'XOM',
        'GS', 'HD', 'IBM', 'INTC', 'JNJ',
        'JPM', 'MCD', 'MRK', 'MSFT', 'NKE', 
        'PFE', 'PG', 'UNH', 'UTX', 'TRV',
        'VZ', 'V', 'WMT', 'WBA', 'DIS'
]

wiki_symbols = ['WIKI/%s'%symbol for symbol in SYMBOLS]
df_components = quandl.get(
    wiki_symbols, 
    start_date='2017-01-01', 
    end_date='2017-12-31', 
    column_index=11)
df_components.columns = SYMBOLS

filled_df_components = df_components.fillna(method='ffill')
daily_df_components = filled_df_components.resample('24h').ffill()
daily_df_components = daily_df_components.fillna(method='bfill')


"""
Download the all-time DJIA dataset
"""
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

# Update your Alpha Vantage API key here...
ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY = 'MYKEY'

ts = TimeSeries(key=ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY, output_format='pandas')
df, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='DIA',interval='1min', outputsize='full')

# Finding eigenvectors and eigen values
fn_weighted_average = lambda x: x/x.sum()
weighted_values = fn_weighted_average(fitted_pca.lambdas_)[:5]

from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA

fn_z_score = lambda x: (x - x.mean())/x.std()

df_z_components = daily_df_components.apply(fn_z_score)
fitted_pca = KernelPCA().fit(df_z_components)

# Reconstructing the Dow Average with PCA
import numpy as np

kernel_pca = KernelPCA(n_components=5).fit(df_z_components)
pca_5 = kernel_pca.transform(-daily_df_components)

weights = fn_weighted_average(kernel_pca.lambdas_)
reconstructed_values = np.dot(pca_5, weights)

# Combine PCA and Index to compare
df_combined = djia_2020_weird.copy()
df_combined['pca_5'] = reconstructed_values
```

But it returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-2808dc14f789> in <module>()
      9 # Combine PCA and Index to compare
     10 df_combined = djia_2020_weird.copy()
---> 11 df_combined['pca_5'] = reconstructed_values
     12 df_combined = df_combined.apply(fn_z_score)
     13 df_combined.plot(figsize=(12,8));

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index)
    746     if len(data) != len(index):
    747         raise ValueError(
--> 748             "Length of values "
    749             f"({len(data)}) "
    750             "does not match length of index "

ValueError: Length of values (361) does not match length of index (14)
```

Indeed, `reconstructed_values` is 361 long and `df_combined` is 14 values long...
Here is this last dataframe:

```
            DJI
date    
2021-01-21  NaN
2021-01-22  311.37
2021-01-23  310.03
2021-01-24  310.03
2021-01-25  310.03
2021-01-26  309.01
2021-01-27  309.49
2021-01-28  302.17
2021-01-29  305.25
2021-01-30  299.20
2021-01-31  299.20
2021-02-01  299.20
2021-02-02  302.13
2021-02-03  307.86
```

Maybe the reason is that the notebook author was available to get the data for the whole year he was interested in, when I run the data it seems that I only have two months?

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy there, I'm the author of the notebook. It seems Quandl no longer provides historical prices of DJIA after the time of writing, and copyright wasn't granted to redistribute the data. For research, you may consider other free stock tickers to proxy DJIA.

The [example usages have been updated](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Python-for-Finance-Second-Edition/blob/master/Chapter06/Chapter%2006%20-%20Statistical%20Analysis%20of%20Time%20Series%20Data.ipynb) in the repo to demostrate KernelPCA, as explained [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html#sklearn-decomposition-kernelpca).